# Rails 3 functions with nested parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, function, parameters, nested

I'm trying to pass a nest of parameters to a rails function defined as so...

```
def test(*params)
    stuff
end
```

If I pass the following

```
test :mark, :was, :here
```

or

```
test :mark, :was, :here=>:today
```

everything is fine. However, when I do this...

```
test :mark, :was=>:really, :here
```

An error is thrown. Any clues where I'm going wrong?

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last argument is a hash you don't have to use curly barces, but if the hash is not at the end of your list of arguments you *do* need the curly braces. In the middle Ruby doesn't know if the comma indicates the next argument or the next item in the hash. So you have to do this:

```
test :mark, {:was=>:really}, :here
```